# How to define an interface in idl file that return a Task

Tags: interface, idl

I'm trying do define an interface that returns a task

```
interface MyInterface : IUnknown
{
    HRESULT myFunction(
        [out, retval] System.Threading.Tasks.Task task);

}
```

This gives me an exception saying 'expecting a type specification near "Task"'

Answer (score 0):

COM/MIDL know nothing of .NET classes such as `Task`, as the technologies are distinct and COM predates .NET.  You intend a server will create and perform a `Task`, while a client (possibly in a distinct process, possibly not a .NET program) will have access to the task?  Then there should be a *COM* interface to the task, with associated proxy and stub implementations for marshaling method arguments and results between processes.  Read up on COM and "COM Iterop".  Also, your IDL will need to define or `import` the definition of such interface.

Depending on your needs, the existing interface `IAsyncResult` may suffice.  It is implemented by `Task`, and it is marked `ComVisibleAttribute(true)`.  Its COM type definitions seem to be in mscorlib.tlb.  You might need to generate the corresponding IDL using OleView.exe.